# Relation between one dummy variable and another numerical variable

Tags: r, regression, glm, survey

In a survey, I collected households with different income categories and the number of ACs that they use. I have to understand whether there is any pattern of income and number of ACs like households with more income using more ACs. I have given numerical codes to different income categories like up to USD200- 1, USD201 - USD400- 2 and so on and so forth till code 10 in excel. The number of ACs are also in numerical digits. NA has been given to households not aware of their income or number of ACs. Using R, how do I understand the impact of income on number of ACs?

Comment: You probably need Poisson regression. `glm(air_conditioners ~ income, data = my_data_frame, family = "poisson")`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.